# Powershell remote session external command execution

Tags: shell, scripting, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I've been playing around with powershell remoting and I've come across a problem that I am unable to resolve. I have a script that creates a remote session and after setting up some variables does the following:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $remote_session -ScriptBlock $block -ArgumentList $args
```

Within the block everything works fine except when it comes to a specific line, at which point the script hangs. The pertinent line is:

```
& '.\external_command.exe' $argument_list
```

When I log into the computer that is hosting the remote powershell session I can see `external_command.exe` in the process list but it's not doing anything. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that external_command.exe is not interactive or can work without UI ?

Comment: @JPBlanc: What exactly do you mean by can work without a UI? When launched without any command line arguments it will bring up a GUI but when certain command line arguments are present it is supposed to work as any other console application.

Comment: According to [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347642.aspx) Some native Windows programs, such as programs with a user interface, console applications that prompt for input, and console applications that use the Win32 console API, do not work correctly in the Windows PowerShell remote host.

Comment: Is the external command a common Windows command or something we can test?

Comment: @JefferyHicks: No, it is a C# binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with remote execution of installers. As a workaround I now first create a cmd batch file through powershell and then run this batch file. Something like this:

```
"c:\external_command.exe argument1" > c:\run.cmd
&"c:\Run.cmd" |Out-Null
```

Comment: I found PsExec and it looks like most people use it as a workaround for solving remoting issues.